# Got error "We are experiencing problems connecting to the Graylog server running on http://127.0.0.1:9000/api/. " in Graylog?

Tags: graylog2, graylog, graylog3

I tried to install Graylog service and followed the instructions below in the tutorial. Here is the official documentation : https://docs.graylog.org/en/4.0/pages/installation/os/ubuntu.html

But after installed I get the following message on the screen.
[image]

I checked on the server logs as well, but no any clue.
[image]

I'm still struggling with several installations, but still no luck :(

- OS version : Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Can anyone help me on this issue ?

Great Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not your case, but from my experience, this is the message I get when I try to connect to Graylog, without being connected to my company's VPN.

There could be some issues with permissions.